# Is there exits WADL file for API's of openstack?

Tags: api, openstack, wadl

I need WADL file for various API's of `openstack`. Is this exists anywhere publicly.??

My system need to pick the file, parse and set up API for the end application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can find most if not all of the WADL files at:

https://github.com/openstack/api-site/tree/master/api-ref/src/wadls

or

https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/api-site/tree/api-ref/src/wadls